# Join Array Of Integers

Tags: vb.net

What is the simplest/best practices way to get a comma separated list of the integers in the Integer array levels?

```
Dim levels(5) As Integer
Dim levelsStr As String

'put values in levels'

'Attempt 1: Failed'
levelsStr = String.Join(", ", levels) ' <- Error on levels'
'Value of type "1-dimensional array of Integer" cannot be converted'
'to "1-dimensional array of String" because "Integer" is not derived'
'from "String".'
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this

```
levelsStr = String.Join(", ", levels.Select(Function(x) x.ToString()).ToArray())
```

Comment: Array.ConvertAll is a possible alternative

Comment: @Jimmy very true, but LINQ is the ultimate hammer and enumerations are the nail.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you could do it with Array.ConvertAll:

```
Dim converter = New Converter(Of Integer, String)(Function(num) num.ToString)
Dim y = String.Join(", ", Array.ConvertAll(x, converter))
```